# Finding all possible valid values of a set based on a list of rules.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

I'm working on a programming project and I stumbled into a bit of a problem. I think it's not an impossible problem, but I'm guessing it would involve some math. It would be amazing if anyone can either help me, or point me in the right direction so I can solve it myself.

The project involves checking the validity of a structure. This is being done by checking if each variable is initialized. Lets say that I create a set up integers from 1 until k from the variables in the structure. These are the indices of the variables, so if there are $k$ variables in the structure then:
$$K = \{1, 2, 3, \dots, k\}$$
When a variable is instantiated, it's index is added to the set $K'$. I know the accent **'** might not be the normal math notation, but I don't know what is. For the rest of the explanation: the accented sets are the actual instantiated variables, and the unaccented sets are all variables that can be instantiated, so:
$$ K' \subseteq K $$
The goal is to check if $K'$ is valid, because if $K'$ is valid, then the structure is instantiated correctly. But there are some rules to this sets validity based on the kinds of the variables, which I'll explain.

Each variable is one of three kinds: optional, mandatory, or grouped. They are treated differently based on their kind.

1. Optional ($O$): their presence in $K'$ is completely ignored. They're not important in this problem. The amount of optional variables is called $o$
2. Mandatory ($M$): all indices from the mandatory variables need to be in $K'$. This is still a pretty simple case. The amount of mandatory variables is called $m$
3. Grouped ($G$): the variable is associated with one or more sets, each with their own "rule", or function. This is the part where I have a question about. The amount of grouped variables is called $g$ and the amount of groups is called $a$

In other words, lets say that we have two sets $O$ and $M$, and a list of sets $G$, where
$$ K = O \cup M \cup (G_1 \cup G_2 \cup \dots \cup G_a) $$
$$ k = o + m + g $$
These sets are mutually exclusive from eachother, except between the sets in $G$
$$O \cap M = O \cap (G_1 \cup G_2 \cup \dots \cup G_a) = M \cap (G_1 \cup G_2 \cup \dots \cup G_a) = \emptyset$$
And the same rules apply to $K'$, $G'$, $M'$ and $O'$

If variable $n$ is in set $G_i$ AND it is initialized, then $n$ is in $G_i'$, so $G_i' = G_i \cap K'$. Checking the validity of the set $G_i'$ is done through checking its cardinality with an single associated function. There is one of three types of functions associated with each set in $G$ (or $G'$): at_least(x), at_most(x) and exact(x). For each of these functions you can assume that $0 < x < g$.

I.e. if variables 5, 7, 8 and 9 are in with $G_i$, and variables 7 and 8 are in K', and the associated function to $G_i$ is at_least(3), then $G_i'$ is invalid. At least one more variable, either 5 or 9, needs to be initialized for $G_i'$ to be valid.

The list of sets $G'$ is valid when all of its sets are valid. $K'$ is valid when both $M'$ and $G'$ are valid. I said that I already know how to deal with $M'$, just check if all mandatory variables are initialized, check if $M' = M$, or check if $|M'| = m$. We can skip this part as well.

Now I can tell my problem: I want to know every possible value of $K' \cap (M \cup O)$ where $K'$ is valid. In other words, I want every possible combination of indices where all groups are valid. Is there a way to not brute force it, and try all $2^g$ combinations?

Also, how would I express this with a mathematical equation? I kinda fumbled my way through the explanation, hoping it was understandable.

Comment: The problem of finding a valid set $K'$ is [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness). [SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) can be reduced to it by converting each Boolean variable $x$ into a pair of variables in your framework, representing $x$ and $\lnot x$.

Comment: Since you want to generate all possible valid sets and there could be $2^g$ of them, the brute force approach isn't unreasonable.

Comment: @Karl thanks a lot! I was already afraid of that answer. If brute force proves to take too long, I guess I'll need add a SAT solver to my dependencies. Do you have any advice in that region?

Comment: @Karl, that sounds like an answer to the question.  Can I encourage you to copy-paste that into an answer, rather than as a comment, so we can upvote it, and the question will show up as answered?  Thank you!